# Gerrit 3.0.4 how to delete submitted but replication failed commits

Tags: replication, gerrit

I'm running gerrit in docker(docker pull gerritcodereview/gerrit). After commits submitted, the replication plugin will replicate commits to our private gitlab, but replication failed.

Now, I'm wondering how to delete these commits, that submit successful but replication failed.

Thanks

Comment: Why did your replication failed? Was it because there were new commits in your private gitlab?

Comment: Because replication auth fail, so I can not replicate commits to my gitlab server.

Comment: Why do you want to delete them, can't you fix the authentication? You can always replicate all the pending changes after you fixed the authentication.

Comment: All-Projects.git should not be commited to real git server, so I want to clear them all.